# Swift Class can not be reached in Objective-C class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a model class written in Swift and a backend service controller written in Objective-C.

Let's say the file names are SomeModel.swift and SomeRequestController.m and it's header.

I don't want to import the `ProjectName-Swift.h` inside the header file. So I have used forward declaration inside the header file. I import `ProjectName-Swift.h` inside `SomeRequestController.m` file.

The Swift file looks like following:

```
import Foundation

@objc class SomeModel: NSObject {

    @objc var prop1: String?
    @objc var prop2: String?
    @objc var prop3: String?

}
```

I can reach this model class in objective-c in the other parts of the code. Forward declaration makes enable to create an object inside the code. So Xcode finds the class. However when I compile it fails with the message:

> Property 'prop1' not found on object of type '__strong id'

How can I solve this without changing the import mechanism?

Comment: how do you declare `SomeModel` property inside the `.m` file?

Comment: I have solved the problem. I'm not sure to delete the question. The objective-c file is in target membership with two projects. The Swift file was in target membership with one of them. I have assigned it to the second project. It compiles now.

Comment: Write an answer for your question or delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Here, I would like to introduce this specific case for those who may encounter with such a problem in the future.

The objective-c file is in target membership with two projects. The Swift file was in target membership with one of them. I have assigned this Swift file to the second project. It compiles now.